# Augur: Getting this error: “Error: eth_call returned no data (0x)” when I try to run any transaction APIs. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Tags: error, augur

The address owns ETH as well as REP according to dev. I'm connected to Rinkeby .

This happens when I run the folling code:

```
const owner = require('./.pvt.js').ADDRESS;
const daiAddress = require('./.pvt').DAIADDRESS;
const privateKey = require('./.pvt').PVT_KEY;

const init = require('./init');

var _extraInfo = {
  "test": "test",
  "2": [ "test1", "test" ],
  "test3": ""
};

const createMarket = (async () => {
    const { augur, connectionInfo } = await init();
    const { Universe } = connectionInfo.ethereumNode.contracts;

    augur.createMarket.createYesNoMarket({
        universe: Universe,
        _endTime: 1556300799,
        _feePerEthInWei: 1,
        _denominationToken: daiAddress,
        _designatedReporterAddress: owner,
        _topic: "stocks",
        _description: "hmm?",
        _extraInfo: JSON.stringify(_extraInfo),
        meta: {
            accountType: "privateKey",
            address: owner,
            signer: new Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'),
        },
        onSent: function (result) { console.log("sent", result); },
        onSuccess: function (result) { console.log("success", result); },
        onFailed: function (result) { console.log("failed", result); }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the following statement hidden in a weird place in the docs:

> augur.api.Market.getDenominationToken(p, callback) Returns the
>   Ethereum contract address of the token used to denominate the
>   specified Market. A Denomination Token is the ERC-20 Token used as the
>   currency to trade on the Outcome of a Market. Currently, this function
>   will always return the address of a Cash contract; however, Augur will
>   eventually support other types of Denomination Tokens.

Changing the denomination token to the value returned by `augur.api.Market.getDenominationToken` solved the issue